# Show that at least 4 of any 22 dates in the calendar must fall on the same day of the week

Tags: proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

Show that at least 4 of any 22 dates in the calendar must fall on the same day of the week

I have a question regarding this proof. When we assume the opposite is true, that is, assume that no more than 3 of the 22 days fall on the same day of the week. Does this mean 22 consecutive days or 22 random dates? Or does it mean that we have to choose 3 full weeks + 1 extra day which would obviously contradict the assumption that 22 days were picked so 21 days were picked.

If any 21 random dates were picked say... 26th july-31st july (6 days), 2nd august-7th august (6 days), 9th august-14th august (6 days), 16th august-18th august (3 days) = 21 days then 4 mondays can be picked, 4 tuesdays or 4 wednesdays so I am confused by how picking 21 days results in at most 3 of days falling on the same day of the week.

So does it mean any 21 days or 21 consecutive days?

Comment: This follows from the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: yes the pigeonhole principle would apply if they were consecutive days but since it is ANY 21 dates then I can pick 21 wednesdays which is > at most 3 @GeoffreyTrang

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid I cannot see which part of your question is the proof that you want to see explained. If you could clarify where the unclear proof starts and ends in your post, we can address your actual question.

However, if you are also happy with a reference so that you can solve the problem on your own, then you should have a look at the pigeonhole principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle The generalized version applies to your problem. The pigeon holes are the seven days of the week, and the 22 dates are the pigeons. If you don't believe the pigeonhole principle, try to prove it by contradiction.

Edit:
After reading some of your comments, I think that the following might be the problem. The proof states: If you pick days from the calendar such that each day of the week appears $\leqslant 3$ times, then you picked only up to $21$ days.
Maybe you understood it like: If I pick $21$ days from the calendar, then each day of the week occurs $\leqslant 3$ times.

The first reading is intended in the proof, and the statement is true. The second understanding of the proof is indeed wrong, as you pointed out in several comments (with the counterexample of 21 Wednesdays).

Comment: It is the first part of the proof, where you assume the contrary. I am aware of the pigeonhole principle. But the 22 dates are random dates and so are the 21 dates. If I pick any random 21 dates I can choose 21 wednesdays each on different weeks which would not mean at most 3 wednesdays were picked, it would be 21

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer that might help. But I still don't see where you cite a proof. Maybe can you edit your original question and make this very precise?

Comment: I think you answered my question so theres no need but I will just double check, so what they're trying to say if if at most 3 days of the week occurs less than 3 times then *at most* 21 consecutive days must have been picked right not random days?

Comment: @computerscienceI don't get what you mean. I don't mean anything containing "at most 3 different days of the week. I was never talking about consecutive days (and I think the proof also never explicitly meant consecutive days). In fact, it does not matter wether the picked days are consecutive or partially consecutive or not consecutive. And what do you mean by "picked right not random days"?

Comment: sorry I am not great at explaining things. You said this: 'The proof states: If you pick days from the calendar such that each day of the week appears ⩽3 times, then you picked only up to 21 days.' Please elaborate on this. Where in the proof does it state that '*up to* 21 days' were picked? I thought 21 days *had* to be picked

Answer (score 0):

It means $22$ random dates. And nobody claims that picking $21$ days *always* results in at most $3$ of days falling on the same day of the week. But *sometimes* it does. Just pick $3$ random Saturdays, $3$ random Sundays, and so on. In the end, you will have $21$ says, with exactly $3$ of days falling on each day of the week.

Comment: I agree with your example but my example I showed above when I picked monday-saturday then monday-wednesday I proved the statement wrong. If it is sometimes true then its not true

Comment: Indeed. And that's what I wrote, right?! That's why there's the number $22$ in the statement of the problem; it's because if you have less than $22$ days, then the statement is not always true. And $21<22$.

Comment: so if I pick 21 wednesdays (as you said any 21 days) then at most 3 wednesdays were not picked

Comment: Where did I say “any $21$ days”?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you said 'it means 22 random dates' and you said '3 random saturdays, 3 random sundays' etc which would mean any 21 days

Comment: Firs of all, I *never* wrote “any $21$ days”. Furthermore, a set of $3$ random Saturdays, $3$ random Sundays and so on is *not* an arbitrary set of $21$ days. Actually, it's a *very specific* type of set of $21$ days.

Comment: That is what my question was, do we pick any 21 days or 21 consecutive days? That's where my confusion lies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128976/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-computerscienceisapain).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use $7(3)+1=22$ to show there are at least $3+1=4$ dates on at least 1 day of the week. Even split $21$ allows $3$ each day of the week, and in any other case by law of averages, at least $1$ day has more than $3$ .  So assume the exceptional case for $21$, then adding $1$ date, forces at least $4$ on exactly one day of the week.